# Masking Audio STFT Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft, masking

I want to implantation a masking time-frequency audio.

In first, I am using the function : `S=spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft)` on Matlab, to extract the STFT of the noise+target signal (from WAV file). After that, I am forcing on some coefficients of the STFT(S variable) to be zero with decision of some threshold. But after doing ISTFT I get complex values ( not a real values like I am Expecting - like audio signal).

Can anyone explain where the problem is coming from? And what is the accepted solution to a problem of this kind?

Note:

If I were doing FFT and there doing manipulations on the signal, I would make sure that the signal has properties to be real in time, but how to keep the properties in the STFT plane?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the MATLAB function spectrogram() or stft()?

I think you should use stft() (because you can use istft() to go back to time domain).

Also whatever processing you do to the time-frequency domain, you should do the same processing to both positive frequencies and negative frequencies.